# updating forgotten password not working

Tags: php, mysql

So this is my code to update the password of someone that forgot it. the problem is, when the user submits the new password, either all of the passwords change to the new one he wrote except his, or nothing happens.

this is my code:

```
<?php 
require('connect.php');
$codeee = $_GET["recov"];


$paso = $confpaso = "";
$pasoErr = $confpasoErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["paso"])) {
        $pasoErr = "Password is required";
    } else {
        $paso = md5(test_inputing($_POST["paso"]));
    }

    $confpaso = md5(test_inputing($_POST["confpaso"]));

    if($confpaso != $paso) {
        $confpasoErr = "Passwords do not match";
    }

    if($pasoErr == $confpasoErr && $confpasoErr == "") {
        $changepaso = "UPDATE users SET password = '$paso' WHERE forgotcode = '$codeee'";            

        if ($conn->query($changepaso) === TRUE) {
            $tellthem = "Password Changed";     
        } else {
            $tellthem = "Something Happened, the password was not changed";
        }   
    }
}

function test_inputing($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data; 
}  
?>
```

So I started trying everything to find what the problem was, and I found out that the $codeee variable that has the value of the $_GET only works outside of the "if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")" statement. So in the $changepaso query, the value of $codeee doesn't exist. Can anyone tell me how to fix that problem? Thanks

Comment: what is forgotcode in SQL ? is $_GET["recov"] populating correctly ? seems it might be blank maybe?

Comment: alot of things are wrong here. Firstly, do not use md5!! Please. Also use prepared statements and throw away mysql functions. Also what do you do with the `$tellthem` variable??

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis forgotcode is a string generated when the user asks for a recovery email. then in the email url recov is equal to that code that i then grab with GET. then i want to update the password of the user using that code. the problem is sometimes it updates all passwords except his, or it does nothing.

Comment: @Akin the $tellthem variable is just used in an "echo" later in the code to notify the user of what happened

Comment: if you do echo $codeee; do you see the code generated?

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis yes if i echo $codeee i can see it